# MS Access 2013 - Getting unfounded Division by zero error

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a routine that writes totals to textboxes to prevent expensive 'Dlookup' processing time.

Some of the totals produce a percentage rate so depend on a denominator.

The error seems to be due to lag of some sort because the denominators are never blank or zero.  For example, as long as there are values in this database - which there are always an abundance of, these denominators will never be zero.

At any rate, here is the line that gets the error ( I get an error 11)

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsSP As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
--->Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("TOTALS_FINAL", dbOpenSnapshot)
```

What can I do to trap this error?  It only happens occasionally and when I tell the use to restart the database (which frees up some resources) it usually corrects the problem.

Here is the SQL for TOTALS final

```
SELECT
    "Total Program" AS BL
   ,TOTALS_COB_ALL_TOTALS.AFP_ AS AFP
   ,TOTALS_COB_ALL_TOTALS.ALLT_ AS ALLT
   ,TOTALS_COB_ALL_TOTALS.SP_C_ AS SP_C
   ,TOTALS_COB_ALL_TOTALS.SP_O_ AS SP_O
   ,TOTALS_COB_ALL_TOTALS.COMMITS_ AS COMMITS
   ,TOTALS_COB_ALL_TOTALS.OBS_ AS OBS
   ,TOTALS_COB_ALL_TOTALS.RA_ AS RA
   ,IIF([SP_C_] = 0, 0, [COMMITS_] / [SP_C_]) AS COM_SP_RATE
   ,IIF([SP_O_] = 0, 0, [OBS_] / [SP_O_]) AS OBS_SP_RATE
   ,IIF(Nz([AFP_], 0) = 0, 0, Nz([OBS_], 0) / [AFP_]) AS OB_AFP_RATE
   ,TOTALS_COB_ALL_TOTALS.UNC_ AS UNC
   ,TOTALS_COB_ALL_TOTALS.AVL_ AS AVL
   ,TOTALS_COB_ALL_TOTALS.ACW_ AS ACW
   ,7999 AS SO
FROM
    TOTALS_COB_ALL_TOTALS;
```

The query right before it just collects totals that are used to produce the final percentages

Comment: The problem isn't in the five lines of code you posted.  Can you show us the basis (such as SQL) for `TOTALS_FINAL`?  Is this code from a form module, or standard module?  Are you using error handling (`On Error Go To...`, or `Resume`)?

Comment: Ok, here is the SQL for "TOTALS_FINAL"

Comment: Nulls might be a problem. Wrap each denominator with `Nz()`: `IIF(Nz(value2) = 0, 0, Nz(value1)/Nz(value2))`

Comment: Nulls are not the issue.  I checked the nested source.

Comment: Please consider these guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes.  Absolutely agree that I need to be brief.  That's why I tried my original approach just to see if anyone knew how to deal with this scenario on the surface.  But when you asked for TOTALS_FINAL - this is a very comprehensive query - but it does provide accurate results.  I just have to deal with network lag every now and then.  That said, I was hoping to find a solution.  Right now, that solution is for the user to restart the application to free up resources.  They are financial analysts who often have an abundance of applications open at one time.  They have been educated about this.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is, that *IIf* always evaluates both expressions even though only one is used.

So use a "double-iif" that divides by one and not zero:

```
,IIF([SP_C_] = 0, 0, [COMMITS_] / IIf([SP_C_] = 0, 1, [SP_C_])) AS COM_SP_RATE
,IIF([SP_O_] = 0, 0, [OBS_] / IIf([SP_O_] = 0, 1, [SP_O_])) AS OBS_SP_RATE
,IIF(Nz([AFP_], 0) = 0, 0, [OBS_] / IIf(Nz([AFP_], 0) = 0, 1, [AFP_]) AS OB_AFP_RATE
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav, I did consider that - but it seemed like overkill for an already complex layering of queries.  The only way for this data to produce a zero denominator is for no records to exist in the table.  I do a set of layering to assure there are no nulls for any record.  I suppose I could add this too, but since I confirmed that there were no zero denominators, I knew something else was causing the problem.

Comment: You can use a `SWITCH` statement to accomplish many of the same things as `IIF`. It's uglier to use, but it short-circuits (rather than evaluating every expression.